# Getting 'Unrecognized expression '$or''/ "Unknown top level operator $or" in my mongodb change streams

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-query, changestream

So the following code works locally without this error appearing. However, when I deploy to heroku, with this code:

```
const profPipeLine = [
        {
            '$match': {
                '$expr': {
                    '$or:': [
                        {'$eq': ['operationType', 'insert']},
                        {'$eq': ['operationType', 'update']},
                        {'$eq': ['operationType', 'delete']}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ];

    const options = { 'fullDocument': 'updateLookup' };

    const profileStream = MatchProfile.watch(profPipeLine, options); 

    profileStream.on('change', next => {
        ....
    })
```

I get this error:

```
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955884+00:00 app[worker.1]: events.js:291
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955886+00:00 app[worker.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955886+00:00 app[worker.1]:       ^
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955887+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955887+00:00 app[worker.1]: MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$or:'
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955888+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MessageStream.messageHandler (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955888+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MessageStream.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955889+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at processIncomingData (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955889+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MessageStream._write (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955889+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955890+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955891+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955891+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:718:22)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955891+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955892+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955892+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955893+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955893+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955894+00:00 app[worker.1]: Emitted 'error' event on ChangeStream instance at:
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955894+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChangeStream.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cursor/ChangeStream.js:41:51)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955898+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChangeStream.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955899+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at processError (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js:571:38)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955899+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChangeStreamCursor.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js:435:5)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955900+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChangeStreamCursor.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955900+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:343:16
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955900+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:736:9
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955901+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js:329:9
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955901+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at done (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:458:7)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955902+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:533:11
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955902+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at executeCallback (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:70:5)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955902+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at callbackWithRetry (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:122:14)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955903+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/command_v2.js:86:9
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955903+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:348:13
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955904+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at handleOperationResult (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:558:5)
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955904+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MessageStream.messageHandler (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:11) {
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955904+00:00 app[worker.1]:   operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 4, high_: 1607530944 },
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955905+00:00 app[worker.1]:   ok: 0,
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955905+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 168,
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955905+00:00 app[worker.1]:   codeName: 'InvalidPipelineOperator',
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955906+00:00 app[worker.1]:   '$clusterTime': {
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955906+00:00 app[worker.1]:     clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 4, high_: 1607530944 },
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955907+00:00 app[worker.1]:     signature: {
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955907+00:00 app[worker.1]:       hash: Binary {
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955908+00:00 app[worker.1]:         _bsontype: 'Binary',
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955908+00:00 app[worker.1]:         sub_type: 0,
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955908+00:00 app[worker.1]:         position: 20,
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955908+00:00 app[worker.1]:         buffer: Buffer(20) [Uint8Array] [
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955909+00:00 app[worker.1]:           183, 174, 253,   5, 233,  29,
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955909+00:00 app[worker.1]:           125, 241,  33, 191,  72,  14,
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955910+00:00 app[worker.1]:            20,  58, 186,  92, 243, 169,
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955910+00:00 app[worker.1]:           243, 203
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955910+00:00 app[worker.1]:         ]
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955911+00:00 app[worker.1]:       },
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955911+00:00 app[worker.1]:       keyId: Long { _bsontype: 'Long', low_: 3, high_: 1599833582 }
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955911+00:00 app[worker.1]:     }
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955912+00:00 app[worker.1]:   }
2020-12-09T16:22:24.955912+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
```

Commenting out the pipeline removes the error when i deploy, so at least I know the problem is with the change stream. I still don't know why it works locally and not in deployment. I'm also using the nodejs event emitters in my project, if that has any thing to do with this. I know changeStreams use the same event emitter library from node.

Any help is welcome; thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include the colon twice here `'$or:' :`, try changing it to just `'$or' :`.

Comment: Omg; I did not notice that; and to think thats been the bug for 2 nights now... thank you soo much!